# Selenium Firefox Profile Path not taken into account

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just want to test locally. With Internet Explorer it works. With Firefox, I get a timeout on line driver.FindElement :

```
var capabilitiesInternet = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();
capabilitiesInternet.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement category = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Name("login"));
});

// Login
driver.FindElement(By.Name("login")).SendKeys("test");
```

Error message is httpRequest to remotedriver timeout.

Upate: I think it's due to the fact that I have a portable version of Firefox 21 and an older version of FF which cannot work with Selenium whereas Selenium launch old version. So I tried to indicate the path of portable :

```
var capabilitiesInternet = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();
capabilitiesInternet.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
string path = @"C:\Portable";
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Unfortunately it keeps running the old version (I cannot change the old version because of corporate environment).

Is there anyway to make this profile work ?

Comment: Well what's the full stack trace? What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? What line is it thrown at?

Comment: @Arran I think I know why see my update but I cannot make work firefox profile path to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is your problem, but in order to 'point' Selenium to where Firefox is located, you are looking for the `FirefoxBinary` class:

```
var binary = new FirefoxBinary("pathtofirefox");
string path = @"C:\Portable";
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have compilation error : cannot convert from Firefox.FirefoxBinary to Firefox.FirefoxProfile

Comment: That should work but unfortunately I got another error message : profile could not be loaded. I have firefox portable in download directory, I can run with command line without any problem but not form Selenium, that's really a nightmare.